# Get all data from form by ng-click AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, form-data

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div class="container" ng-controller="CtrlList">
      <div class="row">          
          <div ng-repeat="x in users track by $index">
              <div><input type=text  ng-model="x.id"></div>
              <div><input type=text  ng-model="x.title"></div>
              <div><input type=text ng-model="x.completed"></div>                 
          </div>
          <button ng-click="submit(x)">save </button>
      </div>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.submit = function(data){
   console.log(data)  // undefined
}
```

So when i click on submit button data is undefined.. how can i get the form data here ? Any help is appreciated

Comment: is the issue still open?

Comment: @Nitheesh Thank you, It is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data here We have to pass origin model.. for ex

```
      <div ng-repeat="x in users track by $index">
          <div><input type=text  ng-model="x.id"></div>
          <div><input type=text  ng-model="x.title"></div>
          <div><input type=text ng-model="x.completed"></div>                 
      </div>
          <button ng-click="submit(users)">save </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the button inside the `ng-repeat`:

```
  <div class="row">          
      <div ng-repeat="x in users">
          <div><input type=text ng-model="x.id"></div>
          <div><input type=text ng-model="x.title"></div>
          <div><input type=text ng-model="x.completed"></div>                 
          <button ng-click="submit(x)">save </button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The property `x` is only valid inside the element being repeated.

Comment: Sorry I don't want multiple buttons here. Thank you, i found the solution and i have updated above.